How can I get the correct positional values such as x/y, left/top from a DIV that had a transform applied?
I have a simple resizable box. When I mousemove, it adds the offset (the amount of pixels, as per my movement) to the width, and we call it a day. This works, the resizable box resizes as it should, but if we add transform: scale(1.25, 1.5) (or any transform, really), the resize function goes haywire. Looking at the width and left/right/bottom, they give somewhat correct values, at times.
I tried reading on this, but can't find any material. I read on the transform-function, and even found a class class that seems to be handling the transforms, but I can't wire it all up.
How do I correctly get my width, so that I can use it on mousemove, together with my offset, when a transform is applied to my div? I imagine it's just looking into the matrix to see if there are some transforms applied, and taking them into account, but I've had no luck.  I read pretty much all Q&A on this website about how different values are extracted when transforms are applied, but they either didn't make sense or were oudated.
Even an answer that points me to a class/package/direction would be welcome, I will come back and answer the question with the code I've managed to write.
